# Efficient way to store data in pgsql to create facet buckets

Tags: postgresql, faceted-search

I have product related data with an fts index on it to do fts search. I know there are multiple ways to create facet results, however I've not found any that have adequate performance with 15+ groups. Has anyone found an efficient way to store, filter and facet the data, that doesn't require tons of queries and gives group-> hit + count?

My dataset isn't huge (60k records) and I realize there are probably better solutions, but it would still be very nice if everything can me done in one db

Approach tried:
https://bun.uptrace.dev/postgres/faceted-full-text-search-tsvector.html#creating-a-table
with 40k items, running:

```
explain analyse 

SELECT 
  split_part(word, ':', 1) AS attr,
  split_part(word, ':', 2) AS value,
  ndoc AS count
FROM ts_stat($$ SELECT tsvagg FROM product $$)
    order by word
```

Excution time 3sec:

```
"Sort  (cost=814.41..839.41 rows=10000 width=100) (actual time=2897.014..3195.353 rows=162944 loops=1)"
"  Sort Key: word"
"  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 27752kB"
"  ->  Function Scan on ts_stat  (cost=0.03..150.03 rows=10000 width=100) (actual time=1246.314..1349.076 rows=162944 loops=1)"
"Planning Time: 0.033 ms"
"Execution Time: 3230.321 ms"
```

Comment: Show a query you would like to optimize, as well as an `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for it.

Comment: I've added what I tried last; my question is aimed and finding what approach works best with lots of facet keys/values to get comparable results to things like typesense/meilisearch/etc (I realize those are specialized tools; but getting to 100msec would already be good for now)

Comment: I would materialize the list and count of facets, such as with a PostgreSQL materialized view, which is refreshed every hour or so.  That list is not something which would need to be up-to-date from second to second.  If you really do need it up-to-date, you could keep it that with triggers, but that is likely to cause concurrency/deadlock problems when inserting or updating the underlying table.

Comment: That blog post you reference seems like hot garbage.  It talks about the performance differences, but never gives the numbers on those differences.  It misdescribes what ts_stat does--it is not "maintained", it is recomputed each time.  And it is misusing tsvectors in a pretty fundamental way.

Answer (score 1):

One way to improve the performance of faceted search with FTS is to precompute and store the facets as part of your data model as it avoids the need to repeatedly parse and analyze the FTS index on each query, but the trade off would be to use more storage. The downside is that you need to keep the facets table up-to-date as your product data changes, but this can be managed with database triggers or batch processes.

The layout you will be looking for is something like -

```sql
-- create table
CREATE TABLE product_facets (
    id serial primary key,
    attr text,
    value text,
    count integer
);

-- populate based on fts index
INSERT INTO product_facets (attr, value, count)
SELECT 
    split_part(word, ':', 1) AS attr,
    split_part(word, ':', 2) AS value,
    ndoc AS count
FROM ts_stat($$ SELECT tsvagg FROM product $$)
ORDER BY word;
```